# iPhone check if user is logged in throughout application

Tags: iphone, ios

For learning iOS programming I'm developing an iPhone application for sharing images. The application is the client for a website.

In the method `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` I check if the user is already logged in.
If the user isn't logged in he can still see all parts of the applications but for example he wouldn't see option button for editing profile, comment on images, etc.

How can I share the logged/or not status throughout all view controllers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** If giving this advice today, I would say use a shared instance:

```
@interface SomeClass: NSObject 
{
    +(SomeClass *)shared;
}

@implementation SomeClass
{
    +(SomeClass *)shared {
        static SomeClass *shared;
        static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            shared = [SomeClass new];
        });

        return shared;
    }
}
```

Then it is auto-instantiated for you on first use, and available throughout your app:

```
[[SomeClass shared] doSomething];
```

---

You can use a singleton - a global, shared instance of an object.

```
@interface SomeClassSingleton : NSObject {

}

+(SomeClass*)sharedSomeClass;
+(void)setSharedSomeClass:(SomeClass*)someObject;

@end

@implementation SomeClassSingleton 

static SomeClass* _someObject = nil;

+(SomeClass*)sharedSomeClass
{
    return _someObject;
}

+(void)setSharedSomeClass:(SomeClass*)someObject 
{
    @syncrhonized(self)
    {
        _someObject = someObject;
    }
}

@end
```

Then, when you need to access your object in another source file, you import the header file for your singleton in the other header, like you would for any other reference.

Create a singleton:

```
SomeClass* someObject = [[SomeClass alloc] init];

[SomeClassSingleton setSharedSomeClass:someObject]; // write to save your singleton
```

Use/read a singleton:

```
[[SomeClass sharedSomeClass] someSharedClassMessage];
// OR
SomeClass* someObject = [SomeClass sharedSomeClass];
```

Or, you can create a singleton implementation that auto-inits the first time you access it:

```
@implementation SomeClassSingleton 

static SomeClass* _someObject = nil;

+(SomeClass*)sharedSomeClass
{
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (_someObject == nil) {
            _someObject = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
        }
    }       

    return _someObject;
}

@end
```

Comment: `@syncrhonized` is for thread safety. In a multithreaded environment like iOS, you need to ensure that a shared object isn't modified by more than one thread at once. A static object, or a singleton like implemented here, exists in memory as only one copy. `@synchronized` locks the object you pass to it, thereby "synchronizing" access to it across threads, so that any thread that tries to access it while locked will have to wait until the lock is opened. This is a basic "blocking" mechanism that blocks the second thread from continuing while the lock is set.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a singleton like the application delegate or as a transient value in a model object (like user data) that everything can see.

If you add an assigned BOOL property to your application delegate, you can get to it like this:

```
myApplicationDelegate *myDelegate = (myApplicationDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

myDelegate.userLoggedIn = YES;
```

Comment: I'm a newbie iOS developer and I never used singleton or model object. Can you give me some hints (articles, if you know someone) for use it? Thank you man!